# Add some properties to a <div> element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-data

I want to add some properties to a `<div>` element.  All of the below works except for the `.data()`.  I cannot see it appear in Firefox/Firebug.

```
$('#menu-container')
  .css('background-image','url("'+big_image+'")')
  .addClass('click_2')                          
  .data("new_link", "new_link.html")
  .css('z-index',"99");
```

Am I doing it wrong?

Comment: When you say you cannot see it, how exactly are you looking for it?  You should be looking for it via the jquery API

Comment: in firebug, I expect to seeit

Comment: Works fine for me in FF 7.0.1 -- http://jsfiddle.net/KEwhf/ -- note: I removed the .css('background-image'...) line so that I didn't have to create that variable.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`data` is not just any ordinary attribute you can add, it is a way to attach objects and data to DOM elements. You can't see it in the HTML source or in Firebug, but you can query it using `.data()`

The data itself is not stored on the element. It's actually stored in $.cache

Answer (score 1):

`.data()` is working but it won't show up as an element's attribute.

If you wanted to see it working you can try `console.log($('#menu-container').data('new-link'));`

If attributes are what you want then you can do `.attr('new-link','new-link.html')`

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
$('#menu-container').attr('data-new_link','new_link.html');
```

it will appear in firebug, and you can also use the expected jQuery behavior

```
$('#menu-container').data('new_link');
```

to retrieve the value stored..

---

But there is really no need to do it this way. It gets stored at the `.data()` collection, regardless of being added as an attribute to the DOM element..